# 'Sandboxing' HTML

Tags: html

I'm building a web application where the user can supply a bit of his own html and it should be inserted into one of the page's div elements.  My only concern is if the user supplies some really awful code.  How do I 'sandbox' his html code so that, if it really is that bad, it won't derail the rest of the page's layout?

Comment: So, only the user who submitted it will see that code?

Comment: Consider employing [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) or some such rather than allow raw HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With an `<iframe sandbox="">`. There isn't really any other reliable way.

Comment: `<iframe>` can still affect the container page with javascript

Comment: To overcome this, you can serve your iframes from custom subdomain or restrict access with `document.domain = ...`.

Answer (score 0):

That's something really hard to do. You could either try to limit/parse the code (to filter out stuff you don't want like unclosed tags (close them) or thinigs like `script` tags or you could show the code in an `iframe` (most browsers will add some protection to it's access rights, especially if it points to a different host (e.g. `http://usercode.mydomain.com/` instead of `http://www.mydomain.com/users/`.

There's no perfect final solution to this and it would as well be based on what you want your users to be able to do. If it's about using some format tags (like available here), then write your own parser, don't just allow them to inject HTML directly (i.e. filter everything you don't whitelist).

Comment: Don't write you own parser, use Markdown.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/

> The Caja Compiler is a tool for making third party HTML, CSS and
>   JavaScript safe to embed in your website. It enables rich interaction
>   between the embedding page and the embedded applications. Caja uses an
>   object-capability security model to allow for a wide range of flexible
>   security policies, so that your website can effectively control what
>   embedded third party code can do with user data.